# How do I attach the cord from a pendant light to a nipple/threaded shaft?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I have a pendant light, it has a cord but no threaded shaft/nipple on it so it can be attached to a bracket on in a ceiling junction box.

I can feed the cord nicely through the shaft but how do I secure the shaft to the cord?

Is there a special piece of hardware I need?

I purchased a threaded shaft like this:
[image: Thread shaft]

And my light fixture looks like this [image]

*Update:* Here is the junction box where it will be hanging (I know I need a [hickey](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimg2.activant-inet.com%2Fcoop%2Ftruserv%2Fimage%2Fg259086.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) for this style junction box which will allow me to connect the shaft).
[image: Junction box]

Comment: "*how do I secure the shaft to the cord?*"   What does that mean. A photo of the fixture and the ceiling junction box would help to understand. The shaft secures the fixture to the box, the cord does not hold the fixture, it only supply power.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I have attached a photo of the fixture. Most hanging pendant lights I've had the shaft is attached to the cord. As in if I hold the shaft the cord is hanging along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different answer, having now seen the ceiling box.  (Thanks to @threephaseEel for requesting that)

You have a shallow box with a chandelier hub in it that will obstruct a typical crossbar and nipple.  You also have knob and tube wiring so I'm hesitant to suggest changing or modifying the box at all.

To work with this box you need to buy an appropriate canopy kit.   The best one I think for this box and this lamp looks like this:

[image]

It includes an offset cross bar that will avoid touching the chandelier hub, and although you COULD mount a nipple on this cross bar, this canopy does not require one.   It includes a compression bushing that is the answer to your original question and just mounts to the canopy itself, you don't need the threaded nipple.   It also looks appropriate for your lamp and it's cheap (about $10 US).

I know some people here frown on shopping advice so I won't be too specific but try searching for a "modern white shallow canopy kit".

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some lamps this doesn't hang from a metal tube with the cord running through it.  It hangs from the cord.  Shove it through the nipple and tie a knot above it.

There are S-shaped plastic dongles you can attach to the cable above the nipple, but those cost about 10 cents more than a knot and do the same thing.  Hopefully your ceiling box already has a canopy (decorative cover) as this lamp probably doesn't come with one right?

If you want to spend a few cents there are plastic bushings for these nipples you could stick into the top to protect the cable, and there are compression fittings where you shove a plastic bushing in the nipple and then a plastic collar screws down on it.  IMO none of those is necessary unless you plan to swing from the lamp.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure why @threephaseEel asked for a picture of your ceiling box, but it's a good thing.  Now that I've seen it, I think you should ignore this answer.  You cannot use a standard crossbar and nipple with that box because the mounting hub you have for a chandelier will obstruct it.

You either need to

- perform surgery on the box, removing that hub, which I don't recommend with that delicate K&T wiring OR
- Buy an appropriate canopy kit, which I'll recommend in a new answer.